# Stripe Checkout with django-stripe: how pass fees on to customers (surcharging)?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, checkout

I am using django-stripe to generate Stripe Checkouts.

I would like to pass the Stripe fees on to my customers ("surcharging").

I found a [help article from stripe](https://support.stripe.com/questions/passing-the-stripe-fee-on-to-customers) regarding this. It says in general how to calculate the fees to put on top of the price of the product.

The problem is, that different payment methods have different fees.
And when creating the Checkout, I must calculate the final price (including the fees I want to pass on) before I know what payment method the customer will select (and therefore what fees the customer will have to pay).

So I don't know the fees when I must put them on top of the price the user has to pay in the Checkout.

Is there a way out of this dilemma?

Comment: Most of the time, companies take the hit (In my experience), so to fee the customer, they average it out with their total profit margin over a period of time. This isn't really a coding question, thus doesn't really belong on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to dynamically change the price based on the payment method presently.  You must specify the amount to be paid *prior* to redirecting your customers to the Stripe Checkout interface.

You could make your users select a Payment Method prior to redirecting them to Checkout (restricting the `payment_method_types` to their selection) and adjust the price based on their chosen Payment Method.  But that requires a lot of work on your side and loses some of the nicest features of Stripe Checkout.